# Abp framework js code doesn't work inside modal

Tags: javascript, c#, abp

.net mvc efcore, no angular, abp 5.3.1

Purpose: Dynamic search within a table.

Method: I create modal according to the tutorial (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-3?UI=MVC&DB=EF). I add table, css and js codes into it. Myinput will filter the word entered in the textbox by searching in the 3rd column of the Mytables table. (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Problem: There is no problem with tables and css, but js codes are not triggered in any way.

```
@page
@using xxx.Localization
@using xxx.xxx.Web.Pages.xxx
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Modal
@model xxxModalModel
@inject IStringLocalizer<xxxx> L
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<style>
    #myInput {

        width: 100%; /* Full-width */
        font-size: 10px; /* Increase font-size */
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; /* Add some padding */
        border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
        margin-bottom: 5px; /* Add some space below the input */
    }

    #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
        width: 100%; /* Full-width */
        border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
        font-size: 10px; /* Increase font-size */
    }

        #myTable th, #myTable td {
            text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
            padding: 5px; /* Add padding */
        }

        #myTable tr {
            /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

            #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
                /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }

</style>
<form asp-page="/xxx/xxx">
    <abp-modal>
        <abp-modal-header title="@L["xxx"].Value"></abp-modal-header>
        <abp-modal-body>
            <abp-input asp-for="Id" />
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
            <abp-table responsive-md="true" small="true" striped-rows="true" id="myTable" border-style="Bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="Column">#</th>
                      <th scope="Column">1</th>
                      <th >2</th>
                      <th >3</th>
                      <th >4</th>
                      <th >5</th>
                      <th >6</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @{
                          var sutun = 1;
                          for (var i = 0; i < Model.xxx.Count; i++)
                          {
                              if (@Model.xxx[i].IsSelected)
                              {
                                  var x= Model.xxx[i];
                                      <tr>
                                          <th scope="Row">@sutun</th>
                                          <td>@Model.xxx[i].1</td>
                                          <td>@Model.xxx[i].2</td>
                                          <td>@Model.xxx[i].3</td>
                                          <td>@Model.xxx[i].4</td>
                                          <td>@Model.xxx[i].5</td>
                                          <td>@Model.xxx[i].6</td>
                                      </tr>
                                  sutun +=1;
                              }
                          }
                          }
                  </tbody>
             </abp-table>
        </abp-modal-body> 
        <abp-modal-footer></abp-modal-footer>
    </abp-modal>
</form>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.indexOf.toUpperCase(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use datatables
https://datatables.net/

and there's an integration guide in ABP docs 
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Data-Tables

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have used datatables in many places in my project, but here I need to use a structure like this.